# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte '

Tags: django, csv, decode

How solve this error?

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte ' .

while uploading csv file in django.
Here view function:

```
def upload_csv(request):
template = "upload_csv.html"
if request.method == "GET":
    return render(request,template)

csv_file=request.FILES['file']
if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
    messages.error(request,'This is not a csv file')
data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')
io_string =io.StringIO(data_set)
next(io_string)
for row in csv.reader(io_string,delimiter=',',quotechar="|"):
    _, created = Company.objects.update_or_create(
        name = row[0],
        hr_name =row[1],
        hr_email=row[2],
        hr_verified=row[3],
        user_id=row[4],
        primary_phone=row[5],
        comments=row[6],
    )
context={}
return render(request, template,context)
```